# Does Capable heal Nux in Mad Max: Fury Road?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-max-fury-road

In Mad Max: Fury Road, when Capable, one of Immortan Joe's wives, finds Nux hidden in the rear of the Rig, he is distraught at having failed Joe. Capable tries to console him and at one point he claims that he is sick. He utters something along the lines of "If the war party doesn't get me, the night fevers will." After this, Capable gently touches Nux's cheek and it seemed that somehow Nux got some colour in his face.

Could it be that the wives, having lived a life in the upper levels of the Citadel with abundance of water and fresh food, have some form of healing effect when they come in contact with the sickly War Boys? (Perhaps another reason why Joe had to have multiple wives) 
Or was it perhaps Nux blushing at the touch of Capable? 
Or did I totally imagine seeing a difference in Nux's complexion in that scene?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probable reason is blushing, her touch brings about a change of color.
As they are war-boys, they must be alien to compassion/affection. 
So when touched suddenly, his face gets back some colour. 
And no she doesn't have healing power/effect. Because if that was so, she would have tried to heal Angharad's leg wound, earlier in the film.

Answer (score 10):

She doesn't heal him in a direct physical way but through a more emotional/psychological way.

Nux is the character with the biggest arc in *Fury road* as his character changes immensely from his introduction till his exit. His mental turning point is defined by the touch from the scene you described so seeing a difference in his complexion is absolutely right.

Here is an [article](https://mishaburnett.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/nux-capable-fury-road/) from Misha who describes their relationship pretty well.